# Do we get the best performance with "batch_size = 1"(especially for LSTM)?

Tags: lstm

In my experience, choosing `batch_size = 1` gives the best result and choosing the `batch_size = whole data number` gives the worst. And seems there is a linear or exponential relation between these two numbers to choose(I mean choosing a number nearer to 1 increase and choosing the a number next to number of data decreases the performance.

So, can we say `batch_size = 1` is the best choice, if you have no limitation of computational system(you have a powerful computer I mean)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent